# How to close a file handle byte[] firstHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(f1.OpenRead());

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which works nicely. However I need to close the file so I can perform file.move() function, this doesn't work because the file is used by another process. I need to use the correct file handle - can you guide me in the right direction?

```
static void DSCheckForDuplicates(string incomingfolder, string incomingarchivefolder, string quarantinefolder)
{
    string[] F1 = Directory.GetFiles(incomingfolder);
    string fname = "";
    long FileOne;
    long FileTwo;
    bool FilesAreTrullyIdentical;
    string FileStatusValue = "";
    string Result = "";
    string NewLocation = "";

    foreach (string fileName in F1)
    {
        // FILE EXCLUSION LIST FROM DUPLICATE FILE CHECKS
        if (fileName.Contains("xxx.DAT") || fileName.Contains("xxx.txt") || fileName.Contains("OrderHead.txt") )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nKnown file type..");
        }
        else
        {
            fname = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            FilesAreTrullyIdentical = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Files present : The file is {0}...Press any key\n", fileName);
            //Console.ReadKey();
            if (File.Exists(incomingarchivefolder + @"\" + fname))
            {
                DuplicateFlag = true;
                FileStatusValue = "DuplicateFilename";
                DuplicateFileCounter++;
                Narative += string.Format("\n________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\nFile Exception :{0}\n####################\n", DuplicateFileCounter );
                Narative += string.Format ("Same filename exists in the two compared directories, Checking potential duplicate file contents in :{0}................\n", fileName);
                FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(fileName);
                FileOne = f1.Length;
                FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(incomingarchivefolder + @"\" + fname);
                FileTwo = f2.Length;
                //if (FileOne == FileTwo)
                //{
                byte[] firstHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(f1.OpenRead());
                byte[] secondHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(f2.OpenRead());
                for (int i = 0; i < firstHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    FilesAreTrullyIdentical = true;
                    if (firstHash[i] != secondHash[i])
                        FilesAreTrullyIdentical = false;
                }

                if (FilesAreTrullyIdentical == true)
                {
                    FileStatusValue = "DuplicationFileNameDuplicateContents";
                    Console.WriteLine("Processed : WARNING!!! identical FILES contents FOUND {0}\n and {1}\n..............\n", fileName, incomingarchivefolder + @"\" + fname);
                    Narative += string.Format("\tProcessed : Please delete from incoming, WARNING!!! identical FILES contents\n\nPLEASE DELETE FILE:\t{0}..............\n", fileName);
                    Result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    NewLocation += quarantinefolder + "\\" + Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n {0}    ->\nMoving to {1} , press any key", fileName, NewLocation);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    //File.Move(fileName, NewLocation);  // THIS DOESNT WORK
```

Comment: take a look here and try using `FileStream` as well as wrapping your code around a `using() { }' to handle Auto Disposing of the object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the stream from `f1.OpenRead()` into a variable & pass that calling `Close()` when your done, instead however you should put the stream and MD5 reference within a `using` construct as currently you leave them undisposed. (This will also close the stream for you)

```
byte[] firstHash;

using (var stream = f1.OpenRead())
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    firstHash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This resolved the issue. The file.move() now works.